# firefox extension security issue

Tags: security, firefox-addon

I'm writing a firefox addon that logs certain user activity and displays some statistics on a webpage.

When the page is opened, the page sends an event to the addon.
The addon adds data to the page and sends an event back, and the page refreshes the statistics.

Now how do I ensure that the extension only puts the (sensitive) data on the right page and not some other malicious one?

Thanks
V

Answer (score 0):

SSL. Unless you're doing something weird, the only route of attack is man in the middle.

Answer (score 0):

The addon will have to authenticate with the server,  probably with a username/password provided by the user.  The server side needs to control what events, and from what user that it can accept from the client side.   Also note that all authentication should be done over SSL to prevent session hijacking.

Comment: I'm not seeing how SSL comes into the picture here...

I have a webpage that doesnt do any communication with a server, all it does is display some data.

The addon gets the data and injects it into the webpage ( in the form of a CDATA section )

What I need is a way for the extension to identify that this is the legitimate page before injecting data into it....

Comment: @rep_movsd I have absolutely no idea what attack you are trying to defend against,  you need to update your question or you will not get a valid answer.

Comment: "What I need is a way for the extension to identify that this is the legitimate page" That's what SSL does.

Comment: Lets say I have a page P and extension E. P loads once from the server and thereafter never talks to the server again (it's supposed to work offline).

E logs data and occasionally adds updates into P. Right now my code just checks if the URL of P is the right one. I am not sure if this is a secure enough approach.

Comment: So then the only attacker would be on the local system,  because P is offline.  You can't defend against a local attacker,  they could just decompile your extension and do whatever they want with it.

Comment: I think that the attack is: a malicious site creates a rogue page that pretends to be the right page and tries to trick the extension into adding the data to it instead of the right one. It's a question of how can the extension authenticate the page. It's not a local attack.